# How to read txt file with some different value

Tags: java

I am trying to read text file by using Scanner. I succeed when I put correct values. But this time, I want to read it with some incorrect values. This method is for reading. Currently, when if statement is true, it shows error. When every if statement is false, it runs well.

```
public ArrayList<Song> ReadSongs() throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(this.file)) {
        input.useDelimiter(",|\\r\\n|\\n");
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String splitLine = input.nextLine();
            splitLine.split(",");
            String title = input.next();
            String singer= " ";
            if (singer.equals("")) {
                input.next();
            } else {
                singer = input.next();
            }
            int minutes = input.nextInt();
            int seconds = input.nextInt();
            int year = 0;
            if (Integer.toString(year).trim().equals("@@")) {
                input.nextInt();
            } else if (Integer.toString(year).isBlank()) {
                input.nextInt();
            } else {
                year = input.nextInt();
            }
            Song song = new Song(title, singer, minutes, seconds, year);
            songs.add(song);
        }
    }
    return songs;
}
```

and I am going to put this text file.

```
aa,bb,2,22,2222
bb,cc,2,41,@@
dd,4,0,2013
qq,ww,2,17,3333
ee,rr,3,25,
tt,yy,2,5,1111
```

Not integer on year in line 2, no singer in line 3, empty year in line 5.
I want to get error message if the values are incomplete. (like, year only accept integer, or must be filled and singer is required)

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: You should check your conditions in the if-statements. In the lines before you set values to the variables used there, which leads the conditions to be never true.

Comment: I doubt you will get it solved that way. For example in line `dd,4,0,2013`: How do you know that it lacks the singer and not the title? In a CSV format file it would must be `dd,,4,0,2013`. That clearly states that second position (singer) is empty. So at first choose a common file format (CSV or JSON or XML) to store the data. Then there are many libraries available to read that file format properly.

Comment: You’re first reading an entire line into `splitLine`, then splitting it without using the result of splitting. Next `String title = input.next();` reads the title from the following line causing your program to parse only every second line. Also @csalmhof is correct: `if (singer.equals(""))` tests the temporary value you have assigned to `singer`, not the value from the file. You need to read the value from the scanner before performing the test.

Comment: I added the question!